# Shift td up one cell

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a dynamic `table` that currently looks like the following:
[image]

The code for the table is as follows:

```
table
  tr
    td LOCATIONS
  tr(ng-repeat="location in currentSchools.Locations") 
    td
    td {{location}}
```

Because the table is dynamic (using Angular's `ng-repeat` right now), I cannot simply place the first location one cell higher. How could I code this such that the listed locations start on the same level as the word `LOCATIONS`?

I've tried using css to apply negative margin-top on the second tds, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
table
  tr(ng-repeat="location in currentSchools.Locations") 
    td 
      span(ng-if="$first") {{LOCATIONS}}
    td {{location}}
```

Comment: Nice.  I put it into a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/xowupevefi/edit?html,js,output) to verify, looks good.

Comment: very clever! The only thing is that you have to put the `span` on the next line, and indent it